# How to perform the Runge-Kutta method with symbolic constant variables?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, approximation, runge-kutta-methods

As I had no clue how to solve a differential equation, I resolved to perform the Runge-Kutta method. Yet the problem was that while there were constants in my differential equation, they were symbolic. The initial method I undertook was to leave them as constants and run the Runge-Kutta method. Yet as by the 8th iteration the terms become extremely large, the process did not move ahead from that point.

The next approach I undertook was to have each constant to have values ranging from 1 to 25 and perform loops for all of them to be able to find a relationship between each constant and the output. Yet as there were 5 constants this approach took too much memory(a couple of GB currently) and an excessive amount of time(currently not completed yet so far, a day and a half).

Now, to get to my question, is there a better way to go about doing this?

As a reference, the differential equation I am running Runge-Kutta on was
\begin{align}
& C_0 \cos \theta + C_1 \sin \theta
\\
& - \ddot{\theta}(\mu C_2 \cos 2\theta + C_2 \sin 2\theta - \dfrac{\mu}{2} C_3 \sin 2\theta + \dfrac{\mu}{2} C_4 \sin 2\theta  + C_3 \cos ^2 \theta + C_4 \sin ^2 \theta) 
\\
& - {\dot{\theta}}^2 (C_2 \cos 2\theta - \mu C_2 \sin 2 \theta  - \dfrac{C_3}{2} \sin 2\theta + \dfrac{C_4}{2} \sin 2\theta - \mu C_3 \cos ^2 \theta - \mu C_4 \sin ^2 \theta) \\
&= 0 
\end{align}
which was given in one of my questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2580454/how-to-solve-or-approximate-the-result-of-the-following-differential-equation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using symbolic parameters within numeric computations tends to be a very bad idea, with the results after a few iterations being horrendously complicated functions of the parameters.

A better idea might be to explore a few terms of a multivariate Taylor series for the solution in terms of the parameters.  Thus if $\theta$ satisfies the differential equation $\dot{\theta} = F(\theta, C)$, $\alpha = \partial \theta/\partial C$ satisfies the equation $\dot{\alpha} = F_1(\theta, C) \alpha + F_2(\theta, C)$ obtained by differentiating the first DE with respect to $C$.  You can then use numerical methods to solve the system
$\dot{\theta} = F(\theta, C_0), \; \dot{\alpha} = F_1(\theta,C_0)\alpha + F_2(\theta,C_0)$ for some particular $C_0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Sorry, I am quite inexperienced in differential equations. How can I find $a$? I assume for $\theta$ I can just rearrange the terms in my differential equation.

Comment: As I said, you use a numerical solver to solve the system.  Your case is a bit more complicated because the equation for $\theta$ is second order:
$\ddot{\theta} = F(\theta, \dot{\theta}, C)$, and differentiating with respect to $C$ gives you $\ddot{\alpha} = F_1(\theta, \dot{\theta}, C) \alpha + F_2(\theta, \dot{\theta}, C) \dot{\alpha} + F_3(\theta, \dot{\theta}, C)$.

Comment: Oh, I think I got it. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I'll look into that!

Comment: I am sorry. I thought I understood yet now I got confused again. Can you please answer these questions(or some of them)?

Comment: Firstly, I understand that under this approach I can remove one constant. Yet if I differentiate them with respect to a matrix containing all the constants, can I remove all the constants from needing to be thought about?

Comment: Secondly, where should I use the multivariate Taylor series? Should I use it to simplify the RHS of the differential equation?

Comment: Finally, I am sorry for the abundance of questions, yet I understand that if the initial values of $a$ and $\dot{a}$ are determined, I can proceed with evaluating it using numerical methods yet what should I do if I do not know them? Or are they evident? Or am I just making a mistake?

Comment: I apologize again for the amount of questions. I apologize also for my ignorance. Yet I will really appreciate it if you answer these questions. Thank you in advance!

Comment: $\theta(0) = \dot{\theta}(0) = 0$ according to your previous question.  These do not depend on the parameters, so $\alpha(0) = \dot{\alpha}(0) = 0$.

Comment: I have thought about this over the last couple of days as best as I can. And if you don't mind, I have a final question and I will end it at that. As $F$ is described by more constants than one constant, such as $C_0$, how can $F_1$ or $F_2$ be numerical values even when they have other constants ($C_1$ to $C_4$) in the equation?

Comment: To put it in the terms of the above differential equation, if $C$ is $C_0$,

Comment: The first term will be $\cos \theta$ divided by the coefficient of $\ddot{\theta} $in the differential equation. The second term and so forth will be a tiny bit more complicated and hence I will not post them here

Comment: My first intuition was that if I conduct a Taylor expansion, I may be able to separate out those constants. Yet while I tried that in terms of all the constants and $\theta$, that was not the case.

Comment: In regards to your edit, I tried looking into the zeros yet I noticed that $C_0 \cos \theta$ and $C_1 \sin \theta$ are always positive and hence cannot approach the 0s.

Comment: My final approach was to differentiate the differential equation in terms of all the constants except the given constant yet I noticed quite quickly that there will always be terms with $a$ s as coefficients where the constants remain. That is when I ran out of ideas.

Comment: I'm sorry for posting all these approaches yet my teacher advised me that showing my approaches is a recommended academic practice, hence I did that. I really appreciate your help so far.(I already asked my teachers and they said they did not know the solution. That is the reason I am asking here just in case you were curious)

Comment: I wrote this earlier yet I deleted it because it was incomprehensive. Yet I tried Taylor expanding using the approach given [here](http://fabcol.free.fr/pdf/lectnotes3.pdf) in the first equation and I managed to separate out the constants. Yet I failed in actually putting it in the form of $\ddot{a}=$ as differentiating by the constants made everything messier(as far as I noticed).